# User Defined RunTime Attributes Set a Color

Tags: swift, xcode, runtime, nsuserdefaults

I have a package from GitHub with custom `UITextFields` and in the User Defined Run Time Attributes there is a field `borderActiveColor` with a custom color. Is there anyway I can add in my own color in the code?

Comment: Please provide source code.

Comment: There is no source code, its in the attributes section

Comment: in code all you need is `yourCustomTextField.borderActiveColor = yourColor`

Comment: Doesn't work ---

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the attribute `borderActiveColor` is not a standard iOS attribute. Is the project in question using the following custom text field control by any chance?
https://github.com/hdoria/HDNTextField

If so, all you need to do is use that UITextField subclass in your project as well and then set the `borderActiveColor` property in your code for the subclassed text fields.